# NumPy ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

I was calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix in NumPy and just wanted to check the results via an `assert` statement. This would throw a ValueError that I don't quite understand, since printing those comparisons works just fine. Any tips how I could get this `assert` statement working?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[3,5,0], [5,7,12], [0,12,5]])
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(A)
print('eigenvalue:', eig_val)
print('eigenvector:', eig_vec)

for col in range(A.shape[0]):
    assert (A.dot(eig_vec[:,col])) == (eig_val[col] * eig_vec[:,col])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it says, it is ambiguous. Your array comparison returns a boolean array. Methods any() and all() reduce values over the array (either logical_or or logical_and). Moreover, you probably don't want to check for equality. You should replace your condition with:

```
np.allclose(A.dot(eig_vec[:,col]), eig_val[col] * eig_vec[:,col])
```

Answer (score 29):

The error message explains it pretty well:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What should `bool(np.array([False, False, True]))` return?  You can make several plausible arguments:

(1) `True`, because `bool(np.array(x))` should return the same as `bool(list(x))`, and non-empty lists are truelike;

(2) `True`, because at least one element is `True`;

(3) `False`, because not all elements are `True`;

and that's not even considering the complexity of the N-d case.

So, since "the truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous", you should use `.any()` or `.all()`, for example:

```
>>> v = np.array([1,2,3]) == np.array([1,2,4])
>>> v
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> v.any()
True
>>> v.all()
False
```

and you might want to consider `np.allclose` if you're comparing arrays of floats:

```
>>> np.allclose(np.array([1,2,3+1e-8]), np.array([1,2,3]))
True
```

Comment: You've covered case (2) and (3) with `.any()` and `.all()`, but is there still an easy way to get the truthy (non-empty list) value of a numpy array?

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper - maybe `bool(the_array.size)`.

Answer (score -4):

try this=>   numpy.array(yourvariable)   followed by the command to compare, whatever you wish to.