# I have ValueError in NumPy

Tags: python

input code:

```
randomlabel = [(random.randint(1,10),i) for i in geneex]
sortlabel = sorted(randomlabel)
store = {}
for i,j in sortlabel:
store.setdefault(i,[])

for i,j in sortlabel:
store[i].append(j)
print store
```

I got the rather cryptic error message

```
sortlabel = sorted(randomlabel)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Use NumPy's sorting methods.

Comment: I don't know it...:'(

Comment: I can't tell what your problem is exactly from the code in your question above but what it means is that you are trying to do something along the lines of `array == True` whereas you should check either if any or if all elements are `True` explicitly.

Comment: I used NumPy's sort, but got a error message...

Comment: The error is setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the array comparison returns the boolean expression.

The Methods any() and all() reduce values over the array.

It would work fine if you replace the code with `np.allclose()`

Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175489/numpy-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambi) ..It would help you out