# Getting ambiguous truth value for string in for loop and not sure why

Tags: python, string, list, search

I have a list of strings called `my_strings`.  I want to pull out all strings within that list that contain `search_string`

My attempt is the following:

```
new_strings = [my_str for my_str in my_strings if search_string in my_str]
```

I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But I don't understand why because I am just comparing two strings.  If I manually pull out a random element in my terminal and do the comparison myself it works fine.

Comment: You have a `numpy` array somewhere, not standard Python types.

Comment: You'll need to give us your *inputs* to reproduce the problem in more detail, but you won't see the error if `my_strings` is a standard `list` object with standard `str` elements and `search_string` being a standard `str` object too.

Comment: You were right, didn't carefully look at the type of `my_strings`.  If you write up the answer you'll get the check.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a numpy array somewhere, not standard Python types; see [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous) for an example with explanation as to why numpy arrays throw this exception.

Given a basic Python list object containing standard string values, and `search_string` being a string too, your code *just works*:

```
>>> search_string = 'foo'
>>> my_strings = ["Let's foo the bar", 'There is spam in my egg salad', 'You are barred from entering the foodchain!']
>>> [my_str for my_str in my_strings if search_string in my_str]
["Let's foo the bar", 'You are barred from entering the foodchain!']
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates:-

```
 ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It means your code contains numpy array then you need to compare like that below :-

```
>>> v = np.array([1,2,3]) == np.array([1,2,4])
>>> v
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> v.any()
True
>>> v.all()
False
```

For more details refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175489/numpy-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambi)