# Python: Using Equality Operator Inside of Numpy Array Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I saw this code in some examples online and am trying to understand and modify it:

```
c = a[b == 1]
```

1. Why does this work? It appears `b == 1` returns true for each element of `b` that satisfies the equality. I don't understand how something like `a[True]` ends up evaluating to something like "For all values in a for which the same indexed value in `b` is equal to 1, copy them to `c`"

`a`,`b`, and `c` are all NumPy arrays of the same length containing some data. 
I've searched around quite a bit but don't even know what to call this sort of thing.

2. If I want to add a second condition, for example:

```
c = a[b == 1 and d == 1]
```

I get

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I know this happens because that combination of equality operations is ambiguous for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175489/numpy-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambi/22175725), but I am unsure of how to add `a.any()` or `a.all()` into that expression in just one line.

**EDIT**:

For question 2, `c = a[(b == 1) & (d == 1)]` works. Any input on my first question about how/why this works?

Comment: try `c = a[(b == 1) & (d == 1)]`

Comment: That answers my second question nicely and works as expected. Do you have any input on part 1?

Comment: your part 1 is too broad. instead of why does this work it would be nice to present a more specific question. That way is easier for me to help you :)

Comment: @Yuca, updated with some more info.

Comment: the best way for you to wrap your head around what's going on is to look at b == 1. without sample data I can't provide a concrete example but if b is an array of size 10, `b == 1` will return 10 booleans. This new array of booleans serves as a valid index for the array a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't your example in point (1) work? This is [Boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). If the arrays were different shapes then it may be a different matter, but:

```
c = a[b == 1]
```

Is indistinguishable from:

```
c = a[a == 1]
```

When you don't know the actual arrays. Nothing specific to `a` is going on here; `a == 1` is just setting up a boolean mask, that you then re-apply to `a` in `a[mask_here]`. Doesn't matter what generated the mask.

Comment: Part 1 does work. The question was why it worked and what to call it, and this answer of boolean indexing is exactly what I was looking for. The post you liked is exactly the kind of documentation I've been trying to find.

Comment: @MatthewSalvatoreViglione you're welcome. I struggled to get my head around the fact that the syntax is actually acting in two independent parts too :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put the conditions separately in brackets. Try using this

```
c = a[(b == 1) & (d == 1)]
```