# 3D graph error: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"

Tags: python, numpy, minimize

I am trying to plot a 3D graph, using a re-existing function to generate the Z values. However, this is yielding the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous". This seems strange, as I am able to generate a list of Z values using the same function and y,x values, but once I include the 3D graphing code the error occurs.

My graphing code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
 
def f(tau,tau_b):                             #re-use society welfare function of tau & tau_b, using corr=0.6
    Z = society_welfare2 (0.6, tau, tau_b)
    return Z

xgrid=np.linspace(1e-5, 1-1e-5,100)   #tau grid
ygrid=np.linspace(1e-5, 1-1e-5,100)   #tau_b grid
tau,tau_b=np.meshgrid(xgrid,ygrid)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(tau,
                tau_b,
                f(tau,tau_b),
                rstride=2,cstride=2,
                cmap=cm.jet,
                alpha=0.7,
                linewidth=0.25)
ax.set_zlim(-0.5,1.0)
plt.show()
```

My society_welfare2 function code:

```
def society_welfare2 (corr, tau, tau_b):
    
    cov   = [[1,corr], [corr,1]]   #covariance
    epsilon_start,b_start = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, sample_N).T 

    epsilon     = np.exp(epsilon_start)  #to ensure epsilon positive
    b     = np.exp(b_start)              #to ensure b positive

    indv_welfares = []
    
    def GBC (t_o):
        taxes_paid = []

        for i in range(sample_N):                     #loop over all agents to find their C1,C2,L

            def consumption_functions(Lguess,epsilon=epsilon,b=b):
                C2 = (((1-tau)*epsilon[i]*w*Lguess) +(1-tau_b)*b[i] + ((t_o)/(1+r)))/((1/((beta**(1/gamma))*((1+r)**(1/gamma)))) + (1/(1+r)))
                C1 = C2 /((beta**(1/gamma))*(1+r)**(1/gamma))
                return -Utility(C1,C2,Lguess)

            result = minimize_scalar(consumption_functions,bounds=(0,1),method='bounded', args=(epsilon, b))

            opt_L = result.x
        
            opt_C1=(((1-tau)*(epsilon[i])*w)/(opt_L**sigma))**(1/gamma)
        
            opt_C2=(opt_C1)*((beta**(1/gamma))*(1+r)**(1/gamma))
        
            income_tax = tau*(epsilon[i])*w*opt_L         
            bequest_tax = tau_b*(b[i])                 
            taxes_paid.append(income_tax)        
            taxes_paid.append(bequest_tax)   
            
            welfare_func = opt_C1**(1-gamma)/(1-gamma)-opt_L**(1+sigma)/(1+sigma) + beta*(opt_C2**(1-gamma)/(1-gamma))
            indv_welfares.append(welfare_func)
    
        total_tax_revenue = sum(taxes_paid)  
    
        return total_tax_revenue - (10000*t_o)

    result1 = minimize_scalar(GBC,bounds=(1e-5, 100000),method='bounded')
    
    opt_t_o = result1.x
    
    total_welfare = sum(indv_welfares)
    return total_welfare
```

The full traceback error code:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3633f4a9db76> in <module>
     18 ax.plot_surface(tau,
     19                 tau_b,
---> 20                 f(tau,tau_b),
     21                 rstride=2,cstride=2,
     22                 cmap=cm.jet,

<ipython-input-19-3633f4a9db76> in f(tau, tau_b)
      7 
      8 def f(tau,tau_b):                             #re-use society welfare function of tau & tau_b, using corr=0.6
----> 9     Z = society_welfare2 (0.6, tau, tau_b)
     10     return Z
     11 

<ipython-input-17-321a709b9684> in society_welfare2(corr, tau, tau_b)
     61         return total_tax_revenue - (10000*t_o)
     62 
---> 63     result1 = minimize_scalar(GBC,bounds=(1e-5, 100000),method='bounded')
     64 
     65     opt_t_o = result1.x

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize_scalar(fun, bracket, bounds, args, method, tol, options)
    798         if isinstance(disp, bool):
    799             options['disp'] = 2 * int(disp)
--> 800         return _minimize_scalar_bounded(fun, bounds, args, **options)
    801     elif meth == 'golden':
    802         return _minimize_scalar_golden(fun, bracket, args, **options)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _minimize_scalar_bounded(func, bounds, args, xatol, maxiter, disp, **unknown_options)
   1956     rat = e = 0.0
   1957     x = xf
-> 1958     fx = func(x, *args)
   1959     num = 1
   1960     fmin_data = (1, xf, fx)

<ipython-input-17-321a709b9684> in GBC(t_o)
     41                 return -Utility(C1,C2,Lguess)
     42 
---> 43             result = minimize_scalar(consumption_functions,bounds=(0,1),method='bounded', args=(epsilon, b))
     44 
     45             opt_L = result.x

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py in minimize_scalar(fun, bracket, bounds, args, method, tol, options)
    798         if isinstance(disp, bool):
    799             options['disp'] = 2 * int(disp)
--> 800         return _minimize_scalar_bounded(fun, bounds, args, **options)
    801     elif meth == 'golden':
    802         return _minimize_scalar_golden(fun, bracket, args, **options)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py in _minimize_scalar_bounded(func, bounds, args, xatol, maxiter, disp, **unknown_options)
   2015             print("%5.0f   %12.6g %12.6g %s" % (fmin_data + (step,)))
   2016 
-> 2017         if fu <= fx:
   2018             if x >= xf:
   2019                 a = xf

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Please provide full details -- where does the error occur?

Comment: Someplace you are trying to use a boolean array in an context that expects a simple True/False.  Where?  That's for you to tell us!  We don't like to guess!

Comment: You have to decide if you want [all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) True's along an axis or [any](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) True's along an axis. We don't know what you want or need. If you search SO with the Error message and read though all the Q&A's in the results you will get a feel for what the issue is.

Comment: Here is one fairly concise explanation: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/22175728/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22175728/2823755)

Comment: @GoodDeeds The error occurs after I run the first code chuck, to generate the 3D graph.

Comment: Was there anything in the error message labeled 'traceback'?  We want to see that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand where the all/any true boolean comes into play. The society_welfare2 function takes in tau, tau_B and returns a number value. What is there to be true?

Comment: @hpaulj Sure, I'll edit the post to include the full error code

Answer (score 0):

The lowest point the trace back is

```
if fu <= fx:
```

That's comparing two variables in an `if`. That will work if `fu` and `fx` are scalars, or single value arrays.  But if either is a multivalue array if will raise this error.

Our task at this point is to trace those variables back to your code.  I suspect you are providing arrays for some parameter, where they/is should be a scalar.

Looking at the top.  It occurs when you ask for the plot, but a parameter is a function call:

```
f(tau,tau_b)
```

and on through a function calls to the `minimize` on the `GBC` function.  I think that `GBC` is the `func` in:

```
fx = func(x, *args)
```

Which raises the question, what exactly does `GBC` return?  It's being used in a `_minimize_scalar`, so it should return exactly one value.

What is its return expression?

```
return total_tax_revenue - (10000*t_o)
```

Do you think you can take the analysis from there?

Now do you see why we insist on seeing the `traceback`.  The error is in your code, but the sequence getting there is long, and not obvious from simply reading the code.

### edit

Oops, I see another level of `minimize`, one that uses

```
consumption_functions
```

It has several parameters, `epsilon` and `b`.  I suppose we can deduce what those are.  But what is

```
Utility
```

The `fu <= fx` appears to be testing the `fx` return value against a bound `fu`.  Assuming the bound is scalar, then the value `fx` must be an array.  Is it???

Comment: The point of GBC is just to set up a function in order to root-find (that is, use minimize scalar to find a # such that 0 = total_tax_revenue - (10000*t_o)).

Comment: I don't care about the purpose.  **I want to know what it produces.**  Does it a produce one number as required by the minimize code, or does it produce an array, several values, as the error suggests.

Comment: On further reading the traceback, I hit a big unknown `Utility`.  See my edit.

Comment: I thought the minimize_scalar of GBC would produce just 1 root (so yes, one value not an array). Whenever I run that code, it produces just 1 value. Utility is a function that returns 1 value as well.