# Why I receive an the "all" function in python error?

Tags: python, function, transpose

Why do I receive an error for the `all` function in my function?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.matrix([[.6+1j,.5], [.6,.5]])
def isNormalcomplex(A):
    if (all(A@A.T.conj() == A.T.conj()@A)):
        print("The matrix is normal")
    else:
        print("The matrix is Non-normal")
isNormalcomplex(A)
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Maybe try: `np.all` --> `np.all(A@A.T.conj() == A.T.conj()@A)`

Comment: You can try `(A@A.T.conj() == A.T.conj()@A).all()` and check [NumPy ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175489/numpy-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambi)

Comment: Thanks.np.all is a solution as well